# How do I organize a vector based on two factors: id and quantity? (C++)

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, struct

So, what I'm trying to do is:
I have a vector of structs.
This is the struct:

```
struct item {
int id;
int quantity;}
```

I will have a vector of them. I don't know how to get it to be organized by the id, except when two items have the same id: In that case, whichever item had a larger quantity would come first. Do you think that an id for its position within its kind would work, or is there a better solution? If there's any other information I should add, tell me and I'll add it right away.

Comment: Sorting by `id` is useful when you have to find in the vector an item with given `id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use predefined sort function and write your own comparator function  and pass it as a third argument.
this comparator function return bool value which tell the sort function the exact order we want.
comparator funtion for your case is given below :

```
bool cmp( item a, item b)
{
   if( a.id == b.id ) // if id is same then sort quantity wise
     return a.quantity> b.quantity;  
   else                // else keyword is not necessary here 
     return  a.id < b.id ; // this means sort the vector in ascending order of                            
                           //id
}
```

call sort function and pass this comparator function as third argument

```
vector<item> v;
sort(v.begin(), v.end(),cmp);
```

here cmp is comparator function name, this compartor function sort the items in ascending order of id and if id is same then they are sort in decreasing order of quantity. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/ here you will find more about sort function.

Answer (score 3):

Something along these lines:

```
std::vector<item> v;  // populated somehow
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const item& a, const item& b) {
  return std::make_tuple(a.id, b.quantity) < std::make_tuple(b.id, a.quantity);
});
```

Comment: IMO, it's better to use `std::tie` in this case since `std::make_tuple` creates a useless copy.

Comment: Mixing lhs and rhs in comparison might perturb some people who might prefer (less generic) trick to transform the field, such as `std::make_tuple(a.id, -a.quantity) < std::make_tuple(b.id, -b.quantity)`.